# Where do people publish/submit their work on type theory?

Tags: soft-question, type-theory, big-list, research-practice

Besides the most common venues (perhaps POPL, ICFP, LICS and FSCD), where else are papers on type theory commonly published?

Especially, I'm looking for more "pure mathematical" venues/journals which publish work on type theory (especially of the more theoretical kind) from time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow the activities of the [EUTypes](https://eutypes.cs.ru.nl) network, and see what meeting are organized. The list of [events](https://eutypes.cs.ru.nl/Events) is growing nicely. As for journals, I can think of [Logical Methods in Computer Science](https://lmcs.episciences.org) and [Mathematical Structures in Computer Science](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science). I can also think of some journals which are owned by you know who, so not mentionable.

Comment: Hm, the E-word company?